# How to redirect parent window from child window

Tags: javascript, html, browser

In my application, I'm opening a new window using

```
window.open("www.example.com");
```

In the new window, there is a button. When that button is clicked, the new window should be closed and the `parent window` needs to be redirected to a new location.
I'm able to close the new window. But how to communicate with the parent window and redirect it ?

Comment: minimal code please.

Comment: The most important is out HTML structure or a minimal code. So we need that code to help you. Otherwise, it seem that you are asking for someone to write some code for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please check these links to learn [How to write effective questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) or [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
window.location.href = 'http://www.google.com';
```

Answer (score 0):

`window.open()` returns the newly opened window. You can pass `window` to it, and the redirect.

```
var popup = window.open("www.example.com");

popup.parentWindow = window;
```

and then in the popup:

```
window.parentWindow.location.href = "www.example.com/anotherpage";
```

Answer (score 0):

In the child window on button click, you can use below call to call the function that changes location of opener or parent window.

```
window.opener.functionnameinParent
```